# How to Do Very Basic AWS Device Farm App End to End Test: Just Run the App for Specified Time

Tags: android, ios, react-native, appium, aws-device-farm

I want to run a very basic test of my (Android and iOS) react native app. I just want the system to launch the app, and let it run for a specified time:

Open App

Optionally: take screenshots every x seconds

Terminate test at specified time (eg run for full 8 minutes, not 'maximum of 8 minutes')

Access performance data (eg memory usage)

Particularly since there are no real actions required, I'd rather do this without having to setup Appium or a testing framework that's going to take a bunch of time to setup, but if Appium or a testing framework is required, is there a complete sample script that I can start from?

I don't need this to run (at the moment) on a large number of devices, so conceivably could start out using the 'sessions' rather than automated 'runs', but couldn't find a way to access performance data in sessions UI.

Bit more detail:
I will build the testing steps into the the app itself (rather than using a testing framework). The closest thing I've found is the built in explorer or fuzz tests, but these seem like they do a bunch of 'interaction' with the app. I just want the app to run. Also, I want to specify the exact time of the test, not just the maximum time. When I ran the explorer and fuzz tests, they stopped the test (not sure what the criterion is) at about 3-4 minutes. I'd like to specify that the test runs for 8 minutes.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps for you [Working with Appium Java TestNG for Android and AWS Device Farm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html)

Comment: I believe iOS and JS more appropriate solution here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-ios-appium-node.html